# Why does v-if not get affected when the data is updated later?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I were to create an element such as that below:

```
<div id="helloWorldDiv" v-if="visible">
    Hello World
</div>
```

and then create a Vue instance for it:

```
var helloWorld = new Vue({
  el: "#helloWorldDiv",
  data: {
    visible: false
  }
});
```

I would expect that the line '`helloWorld.visible = true;`' would show the element, but it has not effect. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yegjhv8/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting started with Vue.js, which is great!

There are several changes you need to do in your sample app. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/f20Ld806/

As you can see in that example, your `show()` function needs to be defined inside the `methods` of your Vue app. Also the **show** button needs be part of the app template, not outside of it.

You can find a lot more in Vue docs and tutorials online.

Comment: One more thing: your button needs to call component methods using `@click`, not `onclick`, as follows: `<button @click="show()">`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for that. So do I create just one instance of Vue for the whole app, not an instance for each element that I want to be reactive?

Comment: You need to have only one instance of Vue for the entire page. The app can have multiple components inside, like header, footer, etc. These components have data models that are centrally managed by that single instance of Vue, and will be auto-updated when they change.

Comment: Ah, that was my problem. I'm trying to port my SPA built in JQuery to Vue, and the documentation made it look like you have separate instances for each element

Comment: Each element can be a component (a custom element), not a full instance. You can have things like <my-app-button> etc. Vue is far more powerful than jQuery, and you have made the right choice

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would suggest not manipulating the Vue instance from the outside.  It'll make it harder to maintain the app as it grows.

However, as to your question, there's a number of issues with your JSFiddle:

- You never set `visible` to true.
- In your `show` function, you misspelled `helloWorld` as `helloWolrd`.
- The `show` function and `helloWorld` variable need to be attached to the window so they can be globally accessed from the `onclick` event.

So if you update your javascript to:

```
var helloWorld = new Vue({
  el: "#helloWorldDiv",
  data: {
    visible: false
  }
});


function show() {
  helloWorld.visible = true;
};

window.helloWorld = helloWorld;
window.show = show;
```

Your code works as expected.